# Can Someone Help Me ID This Marzocchi Fork?

Tags: mountain-bike, fork

[image: Marzocchi 2005 DJ3]
I know it’s a Marzocchi, maybe a Dirt Jumper 3? but I’m trying to ID it so I can do a service and also would like to know the proper air pressure, which I can’t figure out without knowing what model it is.

There are no stickers on it, and there is an 05 stamp on the crown as well as the lowers, so I assume it is a 2005, but holy cow did Marzocchi make a ton of models that year. There are also the following stamps on the crown also.

3114A0209
T05D1223

They have quick releases, and the M shaped lowers crossbar and a slight M shape on the crown as well. Air valve in one side, and a rebound damper on that same side near the wheel.  On the left side of the fork there’s a knob with an adjuster that I assume locks out the fork or something.

Comment: 3 or 4 photos showing the front, bottom and sides as well would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chromed crown in your photo doesn't have the prominent M-shaped lip, the diamond-shape in the middle looks more like the Marathon range.

Marzocchi "2005" (sold from mid-2004) OEM product catalogue, start at page 12: http://www.bartonicek.cz/marzocchi/servis/prehled_marzocchi_2005.pdf